# Parse Android - Delete a Row by Parameter

Tags: android, parse-platform

Im trying to figure out what is wrong with my code.

What im trying to do is delete a row from the server that has a certain projectID

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Project");

 query.whereEqualTo("projectId", pid);

  query.whereEqualTo("User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
  query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
 public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {

 try {
 parseObject.delete();
 parseObject.saveInBackground();
 } catch (com.parse.ParseException e1) {
 e1.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
});
```

Can anyone tell me why this will not delete the record?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `deleteInBackground()` function...

https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-deleting-objects